# Anchor has to be clicked twice before modal appears. Using data-toggle also prevents the modal from displaying the fields

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

Anchor:

```
anchor('students/index/'.$row->p_id.'/#submission/', 'Submit Program', array('onClick'=>'Cchecker.upload_submission(this)', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-medium'))
```

Javascript:

```
upload_submission: function(o){
        $('#submission').modal('show');
}
```

Modal:

`id="submission", name="submission", class="modal hide fade"`